# Do SQL targeted BI solutions like Looker and Chart.io use OLAPs?

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, olap, looker

I know that OLAP is used in Power Pivot, as far as I know, to speed up interacting with data.

But I know that big data databases like Google BigQuery and Amazon RedShift have appeared in the last few years. Do SQL targeted BI solutions like Looker and Chart.io use OLAPs or do they rely on the speed of the databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looker relies on the speed of the database but does model the data to help with speed. Mode and Periscope are similar to this. Not sure about Chartio.

OLAP was used to organize data to help with query speeds. While used by many BI products like Power Pivot and Pentaho, several companies have built their own ways of organizing data to help with query speed. Sometimes this includes storing data in their own data structures to organize the data. Many cloud BI companies like Birst, Domo and Gooddata do this.

Looker created a modeling language called [LookML](https://looker.com/docs/data-modeling/learning-lookml/what-is-lookml) to model data stored in a data store. As databases are now faster than they were when OLAP was created, Looker took the approach of connecting directly to the data store (Redshift, BigQuery, Snowflake, MySQL, etc) to query the data. The LookML model allows the user to interface with the data and then run the query to get results in a table or visualization.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. I have some experience with  BI solution (for example, we worked with Tableau), and it can operate is two main modes: It can execute the query against your server, or can collect the relevant data and store it on the user's machine (or on the server where the app installed). When working with large volumes, we used to make Tableau query the SQL Server itself, that's because our SQL Server machine is very strong compared to the other machines we had.

In any way, even if you store the data locally and want to "refresh" it, when it updates the data it needs to retrieve it from the database, which sometimes can also be an expensive operation (depends on how your data is built and organized).

You should also notice that you compare 2 different families of products: while Google BigQuery and Amazon's RedShift are actually database engines that used to store the data and also query it, most of the BI and reporting solutions are more concerend about querying the data and visualizing it and therefore (generally speaking) are less focused on having smart internal databases (at least from my experience).